# Octopus client, getting version from project name in C#

Tags: c#, client, octopus-deploy

First of, I am completely new to octopus client, used it for the first time just before posting this.

So, I've been landed with this project to update the version number on a webpage monitoring some of our octopus deployed projects. I have been looking around the octopus client and not really gotten anywhere. The best I have so far is:

```
OctopusServerEndpoint endPoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(server, apiKey);
OctopusRepository repo = new OctopusRepository(endPoint);
var releases = repo.Releases.FindAll();
```

From these releases I can get the `ProjectId` and even the `Version`, the issue is that `releases` is 600 strong and I am only looking for 15 of them.

The existing code I have to work from used to parse the version from local files so that is all out the window. Also, the existing code only deals with the actual names of the projects, like "AWOBridge", not their `ProjectId`, which is "Projects-27".

Right now my only option is to manually write up a keyList or map to correlate the names I have with the IDs in the octopus client, which I of course rather not since it is not very extendable or good code practice in my opinion.

So if anyone has any idea on how to use the names directly with octopus client and get the version number from that I would very much appriciate it.

I'll be getting down into octopus client while waiting. Let's see if I beat you to it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess I beat you to it!

I'll just leave an answer here if anyone ever has the same problem.

I ended up using the `dashboard`to get what I needed:

```
OctopusServerEndpoint endPoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(server, apiKey);
OctopusRepository repo = new OctopusRepository(endPoint);
DashboardResource dash = repo.Dashboards.GetDashboard();
List<DashboardItemResource> items = dash.Items;
DashboardItemResource item = new DashboardItemResource();
List<DashboardProjectResource> projs = dash.Projects;
var projID = projs.Find(x => x.Name == projectName).Id;
item = items.Find(x => x.ProjectId == projID && x.IsCurrent == true);
```

The dashboard is great since it contains all the info that the web dashboard shows. So you can use Project, Release, Deployment and Environment with all the information they contain.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to run C# snippets for Octopus automation using the Octopus Client library and I have come up with following to get any version of a project making use of Regular expression pattern. It works quite well if you use [Pre-release](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9) semantic versioning.

For example to get latest release for a project:

```
var project = Repo.Projects.FindByName("MyProjectName");
var release = GetReleaseForProject(project);
```

To get specific release use that has 'rc1' in the version for example (also useful if you use source code branch name in the version published to Octopus:

```
var release = GetReleaseForProject(project, "rc1");

public ReleaseResource GetReleaseForProject(ProjectResource project, string versionPattern = "")
{
    // create compiled regex expression to use for search
    var regex = new Regex(versionPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var releases = Repo.Projects.GetReleases(project);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(versionPattern) && !releases.Items.Any(r => regex.IsMatch(r.Version)))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(versionPattern)) ? releases.Items.Where(r => regex.IsMatch(r.Version))?.First() : releases.Items?.First();;
}
```